# What is the physical interpretation of the conjugate momentum in field theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation

For a real scalar field, the equivalence $\pi^{0} = \dot{\phi}$ makes the concept of conjugate momentum intuitive at the physical level: it is the rate of change in time of the field. This intuition carries over even when we quantize with the commutation relation $[\phi, \pi^{0}]$, telling us that if we know the value of the field at a spacetime point we can't know its value at the immediate later point in time, since we can't know $\dot{\phi}$.

But let's consider a non-trivial example: the Dirac spinor fields $\psi$. There, $\pi^{0} = i \psi^\dagger \neq \dot{\psi}$, which means that:

- $\dot{\psi}$ remains physically intuitive as how the field values change in the time dimension. The physical concept of "rate of change in time of a field" exists for all types of fields.
- $\pi^{0}$ has lost all sort of intuition. I don't know what it represents anymore other than simply repeating like a parrot "it's $i \psi^\dagger$". But there must be a **definition** for $\pi^{0}$, as in "$\pi^{0}$ *is the variable that would allow us to know how the field behaves under translations in...*" or something similar, that is **valid for all types of fields** at that can be applied to both the scalar and the spinor cases, allowing us to at least infer something about $\pi^{0}$ even before looking at $i \psi^\dagger$.

My question is: Given a field that transforms as an arbitrary representation of the Lorentz group, what is the universally valid meaning of the conjugate momentum?

Comment: The conjugate/canonical momentum $\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial\dot{\phi}}$ is not always the kinetic momentum. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/593313/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298629/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109707/2451 General tip: Look at related posts in the right margin.

Comment: thank you, i edited the title to make it clear that the Dirac case was just a representative of the non-trivial cases, as my question in more universal (as explicit in the last paragraphs)

Comment: The general case is tackled in the second link (What is the physical meaning of the canonical momentum field in quantum field theory?) and should answer your question

Comment: I more than agree with the above @LPZ comment: momentum is a shifter (translator) of its conjugate, and rarely identifies with the time derivative of the conjugate quantity, even in classical mechanics (think non-Cartesian coordinate systems).

Comment: what does "shifter (translator) of its conjugate" mean? can you explain it with respect to field theory?

Comment: @CosmasZachos For the fermionic field in second quantization, I don't think you can write down the analog of $e^{ic\pi(\vec x)}$, since in the fermionic theory $\pi(\vec x) = i\psi(\vec x)^\dagger$ is not Hermitian, so $e^{ic\pi(\vec x})$ is not unitary. In the classical Grassman theory of fermions the pi field might be the generator of translations (I dont remember)... but in the usual second quantized theory, I don't think there is such a direct analog for the bare $\pi(\vec x)=i\psi(\vec x)^\dagger$ field.

Comment: (Although, we can still use the formula $\vec P = -\int d^3x \pi(\vec x)\vec \nabla\phi =-\int d^3x i\psi(\vec x)^\dagger\nabla\psi$ for the total momentum. So the conjugate momentum field convolved with the derivative of the field still generates translations, but the bare conjugate momentum field doesn't shift the field in the same way...)

Comment: @htf For sure, but I don't think the questioner is puzzled by the Grassmann variable statistics; suitably generalizing the commutator to the [graded commutator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/794492/66086)  addresses all analogies with suitable signs. Supersymmetry breaking and Goldstone fermions readily provides graded analogs of the bosons statements/motions. The crucial point is translation in some field space.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Interesting. Thanks for the link!

Comment: A *very* sloppy formal-wisecrack mnemonic for Grassmann translation is but $e^{\int dy \psi^\dagger (y)\epsilon } \psi(x) e^{-\int dy \psi^\dagger (y)\epsilon}= (1+\int dy \psi^\dagger(y)\epsilon ) \psi(x) (1-\int dy \psi^\dagger(y)\epsilon ) = \psi(x) - \epsilon$, or something of the sort...

Comment: Good supersymmetry intros do it nicely.

Answer (score 5):

> I more than agree with the above @LPZ comment: momentum is a shifter (translator) of its conjugate, and rarely identifies with the time derivative of the conjugate quantity, even in classical mechanics (think non-Cartesian coordinate systems). (CZ)

> -What does "shifter (translator) of its conjugate" mean? can you explain it with respect to field theory? (TK6)

I can hardly explain it better than the cited [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/299235/66086). *π* is the infinitesimal field-space translation operator of its conjugate field *φ*, at *equal times*, by dint of the field-space canonical commutation relation,
$$[\phi(\mathbf{x}),\, \pi(\mathbf{y})] = i  \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}).$$
It is logically unlinked to time derivation, except in special settings, such as scalar field theory, which prompted you to misframe its fundamental role.

It is  hardly different than *p* infinitesimally translating *x* in plain QM, and thus effecting a finite translation when exponentiated, thus the [Lagrange shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator).

In elementary QM,
$$
e^{ic\hat p} f(\hat x) e^{-ic\hat p} = f(\hat x+c\hbar) .
$$
For several variables,
$$
e^{ic\hat p_k} f(\hat x_j) e^{-ic\hat p_k} = f(\hat x_j+\delta_{jk}c\hbar) ,
$$
where no repeated index summation is implied.

Mutatis mutandis, in QFT,
$$
e^{ic  \pi(\mathbf{y}) }  \phi(\mathbf{x})  e^{-ic  \pi(\mathbf{y})} =  \phi(\mathbf{x}) +c \delta (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}), \leadsto \\
e^{ic \int\! dy~ \pi(\mathbf{y}) }  \phi(\mathbf{x}) ~ e^{-ic  \int \! dy'~\pi(\mathbf{y'})} =  \phi(\mathbf{x}) +c  ,
$$
significant in SSB, and so forth.

This is the essential formal role and function of *π*, the time derivation being basically incidental, as you noticed in your question. Typically, the leading behavior of "spontaneously broken" charges consists of linear combinations (space integrals) of canonical field momenta of Goldstone fields, bosons or fermions.

Comment: Translation in field space, at a given fixed (equal) time, not a physical dimension!! Recall space-time is just a set of bland indices in QFT, ***not*** dynamical variables! Moreover, there only one canonical momentum in QFT, what you call (superfluously) $\pi^0$. The spacelike gradients of φ are not canonical variables, just differences of φ s at the same time. Good QFT texts pin all these points down.

Comment: do you have chapter references from literature that explain in depth & nicely the role of the conjugate momentum as the "translator of the field in field space"?

Comment: Not right off the bat. Schwartz ch 2.3.3. comes close, Hatfield, Weinberg I, perhaps; but no, I do not recall one that has answered this narrow question right away... You might expect the ones dealing with QFT Noether's theorem and SSB to be more spot on, as nonlinear symmetry realizations are at the heart of field translations/shifts.

Comment: What is the physics behind the reason for Planck's constant in your first expression?

Comment: The canonical commutation relation of Born. Usually it is nondimensionalized to unity, but I copied it off that answer. I now nondimensionalized it out of the QFT expressions, as most students get introduced to nondimensionalized oscillators, except, perhaps in phonon intros, and might be distracted by it. The $\hbar$ is always there, implicitly, making loops and anomalies "quantum", of course.

Answer (score -1):

> For a real scalar field, the equivalence $\pi^{0} = \dot{\phi}$ makes the concept of conjugate momentum intuitive at the physical level: it is the rate of change in time of the field.

This is true when the Lagrangian has a $\frac{1}{2}\dot \phi^2$ term and no other $\dot\phi$ dependence. However, in general, regardless of the $\dot \phi$ dependence of the Langrangian, we define the canonical momentum as:
$$
p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\;.
$$

Or, in field theory:
$$
\pi(\vec x) = \frac{\delta L}{\delta \dot \phi(\vec x)}\;.
$$

Or, more precisely, we always use the above definitions in classical mechanics and classical field theory. And we always look to these definitions for heuristic guidance when we perform canonical quantization (or "anti-canonical" quantization for fermions.)

> - $\pi^{0}$ has lost all sort of intuition. I don't know what it represents anymore other than simply repeating like a parrot "it's $i \psi^\dagger$". But there must be a **definition** for $\pi^{0}$,

Yes, there is still a definition:
$$
\pi(\vec x) = \frac{\delta L}{\delta \dot \phi(\vec x)}\;,
$$
which can still be used regardless of whether the functional differentiation variable is denoted $\phi$ or $\psi$.

There is, however, a problem with the quantization of the Dirac field. Namely, we can **not** perform "canonical" quantization in the strict sense of implementing a canonical **commutator**:
$$
[\phi(\vec x),\pi(\vec y)] = [\psi(\vec x), i\psi(\vec y)^\dagger] \stackrel{?!}{=} i\delta(\vec x - \vec y)\;.
$$

Rather, we have to implement an *anti*-commutator:
$$
\{\phi(\vec x),\pi(\vec y)\} = \{\psi(\vec x), i\psi(\vec y)^\dagger\} {=} i\delta(\vec x - \vec y)\;.
$$

> as in "$\pi^{0}$ *is the variable that would allow us to know how the field behaves under translations in...*" or something similar,

In bosonic quantum field theories, it is straight-forward to see that the $\pi(\vec y)$ field still generates translations of the $\phi(\vec x)$ field, in the analogous sense as it does in classical mechanics of $N$ particles. (I.e., $\phi(\vec x)\to\phi(\vec x)+c\delta(\vec x - \vec y)$.)

However, there are problems with a straightforward analog for fermionic fields, due to the anticommutation relations.

---

To see how this is straightforward for a bosonic field recall, in classical mechanics of $N$ particles, we have
$$
p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i}\;.
$$

In classical mechanics, we also recall, a *canonical* transformation can be implemented to change variables $(q,p)\to (\tilde q, \tilde p)$ without changing the form of Hamilton's equations of motion.

And, we also recall, that a special type of canonical transformation called an [infinitesimal canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Infinitesimal_canonical_transformation) can be implemented by considering a generating function:
$$
F = \vec q\cdot \vec {\tilde p} + \alpha G\;,
$$
where $\alpha$ is a "small" parameter. And where, somewhat confusingly, we also call the function $G$ the "generator" of the infinitesimal translation.

In classical mechanics of $N$ particles, we can consider the generator $G$ to be the momentum $p_j$ itself. In which case, by the usual rules of classical mechanics, we have (with $G=p_j$):
$$
p_i = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} = \tilde p_i + \alpha\frac{\partial G}{\partial q_i} = \tilde p_i
$$
and
$$
\tilde q_i = \frac{\partial F}{\partial \tilde p_i}= q_i + \alpha\frac{\partial G}{\partial \tilde p_i} = q_i + \alpha\frac{\partial G}{\partial p_i} + O(\alpha^2) = q_i + \alpha\delta_{ij}\;, 
$$
where the final equality ignores higher order terms in $\alpha$. In other words, the momentum $p_i$ *generates shifts of its conjugate partner $q_i$*.

In classical field theory (and bosonic field theory) we similarly have canonical transformations and we can similarly set the generator to $G=\pi(\vec x)$, in which case we have:
$$
\pi(\vec x) = \tilde \pi(\vec x)
$$
and
$$
\tilde \phi(\vec x) = \phi(\vec x) + \alpha\delta(\vec x - \vec y)\;.
$$

---

> that is **valid for all types of fields** at that can be applied to both the scalar and the spinor cases, allowing us to at least infer something about $\pi^{0}$ even before looking at $i \psi^\dagger$.
>
> My question is: given a field that transforms as an arbitrary representation of the Lorentz group, what is the universally valid meaning of the conjugate momentum?

To glean some kind of "universally valid" meaning for the *quantum field* other than the definition:
$$
\pi = \frac{\delta L}{\delta \dot\phi}
$$
we can look at the momentum operator itself.

Recall, the momentum operator for a real scalar field is:
$$
\vec P = -\int d^3x \pi \vec \nabla \phi\;.\tag{A}
$$

The definition in Eq. (A) also holds for fermionic fields:
$$
\vec P = -\int d^3x (i\psi^\dagger)\vec \nabla \psi=\int d^3x \psi^\dagger (-i\vec \nabla\psi)\;,
$$
so, $\pi$ has the same meaning when convolved with $\nabla\phi$ in both bosonic and fermionic quantum field theories.

However, we can not straightforwardly write a direct analog of:
$$
U_j = e^{i p_j \delta q}
$$
when our field is fermionic, since in this case the analog of $p_i$ is not Hermitian, so the $U$ operator would not be unitary.

Comment: So does this mean that $\pi$, when convolved with ∇ (in both fermionic&bosonic qft) is the operator that gives you the 4-momentum of a state? this is clear in the scalar field case; is it so also for the other cases (when $\pi$ is different than the time derivative of the field)?

Comment: For the KG field and the Dirac field, integrating $\pi$ against $-\vec \nabla \phi$ gives the total three-momentum (usual momentum). This is true when $\pi$ is the time derivative of the field (KG case) and also true when $\pi$ is not the time derivative of the field (Dirac case). Those are the only two cases I looked at explicitly.